# How to change current keyboard layout in .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, keyboard

I need command to change current GLOBAL keyboard layout (change en_US to ru_RU for example). It must be command for Windows .bat file (not PowerShell file).
This thing must work on 7.

I add a language with

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
       <gs:UserList>
       <gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
       </gs:UserList>
       <gs:InputPreferences> 
       <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0423:00000423"/> 
       </gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Add I need to make all windows applications use this language for keyboard input

Comment: Let us know how you got on when you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50299640/edit), and add your code.

Comment: Is rebooting the machine acceptable?

Comment: This is more of a [SuperUser] kind of question.